# Is angular2-highcharts supported in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular11

I was using https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts

```
npm i angular2-highcharts
```

It was working perfectly fine till my source code environment was Angular 8 but after upgrading to Angular 11 it is not working as expected. I was getting injector error on HighchartsStatic.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

export function highchartsFactory() {
   const hc = require( 'highcharts/highstock' );
    const dd = require( 'highcharts/modules/exporting' );

    hc.setOptions( {
        lang: {
            numericSymbols: [" K", " M", " B", " T", " P", " E"],
            thousandsSep: ",",
            decimalPoint: ".",
            stockTools: {
                gui: {
                    inputText: 'Text annotation from input'
                }
            },
            navigation: {
                popup: {
                    inputText: 'Input text'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y',
            valueDecimals: 2 
        },
        time: {
            timezoneOffset: (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() 
        },
        global: {
            timezoneOffset: (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()
        }
    } );
    
    dd( hc );
    // const annotations = require('highcharts-annotations/js/annotations');
    // annotations(hc);
    const ind = require( 'highcharts/indicators/indicators-all' );
    ind( hc );
    const annotationsAdvanced = require( './highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced.src' );
    annotationsAdvanced( hc );
    const priceIndicators = require( 'highcharts/modules/price-indicator' );
    priceIndicators( hc );
    const fullScreen = require( 'highcharts/modules/full-screen' );
    fullScreen( hc );
    const stockTools = require( 'highcharts/modules/stock-tools' );
    stockTools( hc );
    const dragPanes = require( 'highcharts/modules/drag-panes' );
    dragPanes( hc );
    const boost = require( 'highcharts/modules/boost' );
    boost( hc );
    
    return hc;
}
```

And my Ngmodule is:

```
@NgModule( {
    providers: [{
                  provide: HighchartsStatic,
                  useFactory: highchartsFactory
                }]
})
```

I browse through many blogs they suggesting to use *highcharts-angular* but it will be a big change in my project. Is there any way I can use it or fix this issue ?

Also I want to know the Angular support of **angular2-highcharts**

Answer (score 1):

`highcharts-angular` is the official Highcharts wrapper for Angular so It would be a good long term investement for you to switch from `angular2-highcharts` to `highcharts-angular`.

You can clearly see from the npm download stats that `highcharts-angular` is more popular (55k weekly downloads vs 5k weekly downloads )

And it cleary says in the github repo **Not supported anymore.
Consider using the offical Highcharts wrapper for Angular**

Comment: yes I get your point Rachid Oussanaa. May be I will update if necessary. But I could not find my answer. This is only my question whether that angular2-highcharts supported in angular 11 ?

Comment: your project was working with Angular8 because that version uses the "View Engine" compiler while Angular11 uses the Ivy compiler. The short answer answer to your question is NO. angular2-highcharts does not support the new "Ivy compiler"